# Custom Blur on MKMapView

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I'm trying to get a blur on a MKMapView like in the picture. [image]

I've been fooling around with using UIToolbar to create the blur but I can't get it as custom as I want, the blur is too thick and not transparent enough. Anyone have any ideas as for what I can try to get this effect?

Comment: Use the UIView and put scale for it OR transparent effect to it...

Comment: The UIView? I'm sorry, you're going to have to rephrase that, doesn't really make sense. What transparent effect?

Comment: @KumarKl could you try to explain again?

Comment: Add the UIView as like in the position of your need and make that backgroud color as [UIColor lightTextColor]; OR set alpha to it (0.20 to 0.40 .....)

Comment: @KumarKl but I need a blur effect...and that's just transparency.

Comment: Try that, for backgroud color . Its almost the as blur for the background

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. Thanks though.

Comment: Should the blur be attached to specific coordinates on the map, like an overlay? Or should a fixed part of the map viewport be blurred, like a floating view?

Comment: @esker it should be attached :)